# Deleting a linked list node in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Im trying to shift from c to c++ and Im working with linked lists. I have the list building correct(I think) but I am having problems deleting the list. I am not sure why though. Half the time I get a seg fault and the other half it only goes through the deletion loop once before the program closes. So I am kind of lost. Heres the code

Functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ll.h"
```

using namespace std;

```
student::student()
{
cout<<"\nWhat is the name of the student? "<<flush;
cin>>this->name;
cout<<"What id of the student? "<<flush;
cin>>this->id;
cout<<"\n";
}



void student_list::new_student()
{
if(head==NULL)
    {
    cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
    head=new student;
    head->next=NULL;
    tail=head;
    }
else
    {
    tail->next=new student;
    tail=tail->next;
    tail->next=NULL;
    }
}

student_list::student_list()
{
head=tail=NULL;
}

void student_list::print()
 {
class student *walk; walk=head;
while(walk!=NULL)
    {
    cout<<walk->name<<": "<<walk->id<<endl;
    walk=walk->next;
    }
}

void student_list::deleter()
{
int x;
student *walk;
walk=head;
cout<<"test"<<endl;
while(walk!=NULL)
    {
    cout<<head->id<<endl;
    delete head;
    head->next=NULL;
    head=walk->next;
    walk=walk->next;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ll.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
class student_list list;
int x, y, z;
cout<<"How many tests? "<<flush;
cin>>y;
for(x=0; x<y; x++)
    {
    list.new_student();
    }
list.print();
list.deleter();
cout<<"test1";
return 0;
}
```

And the header:

```
    #ifndef __LLFUNC_H_INCLUDED__
#define __LLFUNC_H_INCLUDED__


#include <string>   

class student{
public:
    student *next;
    int id;
    std::string name;
public:
    student();
};  

class student_list{
private:
    student *head;
    student *tail;
public:
    student_list();
    void new_student();
    void print();
    void deleter();
};
#endif
```

Comment: Just save yourself from the hassle and use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: What about inspecting the pointer values for validity, when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: @EdHeal I know it's much argued here, but please use this reference [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: I'm eventually going to move to STLs but I want to understand and be able to code the linked lists myself first.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Why? It is a reasonable reference.

Comment: Placing input from console into constructors is evil.  Whenever you want an instance of the class, it will input data from the User.  A better design is to separate input from construction, IOW, write a separate input method.

Comment: @EdHeal I finally prefer cppreference.com personally, because I found it turned out to be more up to date with the latest standard definitions, and shows less outdated samples or wrong tutorials. As mentioned, it's much argued about this here ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Mose of this stuff is more or less static. Also when does one use the latest compiler. unless you like to live on the bleeding edge!

Comment: @EdHeal No, it's not reasonable. It's bad and full of mistakes and oversights.

Comment: @EdHeal _"unless you like to live on the bleeding edge!"_ I presume this is essential somehow! (watch out, I became 50 this year :-P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `walk->next=NULL` right before you attempt to iterate to it, try storing the 'next' pointer before you null it out and delete the current item. I've also removed `walk` since it is completely unnecessary, as you are already using `head` to iterate through everything.

```
void student_list::deleter()
{
int x;
cout<<"test"<<endl;
while(head!=NULL)
    {
    student *next = head->next; // Store the next item now.
    cout<<head->id<<endl;
    head->next=NULL;
    delete head;
    head=next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For deleting or inserting items in a singly linked list, the common advice is to maintain two pointers, one pointer for the present node and another for the previous node.

In the case of deleting, the operation would be:

```
// Make the previous node point the the node that
// the next node points to.
p_node->next = p_present->next; 

// Null out the link field of the present node,
// for safety purposes.
p_present->next = NULL;

// Delete the present node.
delete p_present;
```

I have purposely left out some vital error checking here.

Answer (score 0):

You delete function has bug

```
void student_list::deleter()
{
......
while(walk!=NULL)
    {
    ......
    delete head;
    head->next=NULL;
    ......
    }
 }
```

You have to re-order deletion/assignment

```
void student_list::deleter()
{
int x;
student *walk;
walk=head;
cout<<"test"<<endl;
while(walk!=NULL)
    {
    cout<<walk->id<<endl;
    walk = walk->next;
    delete head;
    head = walk;
    }
}
```